# Google Sites script to change permission to "Public on the web"

Tags: google-sites

I am using the Google script code, "SitesApp.copySite" to copy an existing site hundreds of time. (I am making a course website for every course in our high school). The master site is "Public on the web". When a make a copy of it, the copy becomes "Private". I am using the command "siteToUpdate.addOwner(emailAddress);" to add the teacher in as owner.

I can not find any way to make the site "Public on the web" again, besides going in manually to each site and changing it. Does anyone know how to do this in code?

Thanks